# LINQ-2-SQL expansion of relationships on ToList()

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a DataLayer class (LINQ2SQL, not entity framework) that returns rows from the database as follows:

```
    public ReadOnlyCollection<UserCars> Cars
    {
        get
        {
            using (var context = new TransportopiaDataContext())
            {
                var result = (from car in context.UserCars
                              where car.UserId == UserId
                              select car);
                return result.ToList().AsReadOnly();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, as you know, you have to do the ToList() because the datacontext goes out of scope when you leave the using() clause.  The problem is that there are foreign key relationships; while the context is still in scope, you could do:

```
string foo = car.Manufacturer.Name;
```

But doing that after context has been disposed causes an error.  So my question is:

"Is there some way of doing the ToList() such that foreign key relationships will also be expanded?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify this in the  `DataLoadOptions` before executing your query:

```
using (var context = new TransportopiaDataContext())
{
    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<UserCar>(x => x.Manufacturer);
    context.LoadOptions = options;
    var result = (from car in context.UserCars
                    where car.UserId == UserId
                    select car);
    return result.ToList().AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  It works.

My first guess, which wasn't sufficient, was to set context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false.  Does that just cause the data to be loaded right in the "var result =" clause, but still without the relationships?

Comment: @Dave: Yes, setting `DeferredLoadingEnabled` to false just will disable subsequent queries on the `UserCar` instances you initially return - so it will stop the context disposed error from occurring but still wouldn't load any related data/tables.